# Name some non-trivial sites written using IronPython & Silverlight

Tags: python, silverlight, ironpython, web

Just what the title says. It'd be nice to know a few non-trivial sites out there using [Silverlight in Python](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SilverlightInteractiveSession&referringTitle=Home).

Answer (score 2):

My current job is writing business apps for a German / Swiss media media consortium using IronPython and Silverlight. We're gradually moving all our web apps over to IronPython / Silverlight as they are faster to build, look nicer and perform better than the Javascript equivalents.

Definitely not trivial, but not public either I'm afraid (although there our main app may be used by customers - advertisers - when we port that over).